# A no-op device for function pointer tables?

Tags: c, lookup

```
void table_no_op()
{
// this is for function table elements that do nothing,
// fills space between states, use less of them
    return;
}
```

I am currently using this to define a "zero" in a function pointer table, where the input index is supposed to do nothing.  Is it okay or something glaringly wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there's nothing wrong with the no-op per se (in general, this is called Null Object Pattern), I would be worried about the function declaration - i.e. does every function in the table take 0 arguments and return void?

A counterexample would be OpenGL where you often retrieve a pointer to function and cast it to the desired type yourself - but casting a void->void pointer to something else, e.g. (int, int)->int would be undefined behavior and likely cause crash (or uninitialized return value, or else).

So, if the functions in the table are homogeneous - go for it. If not - better do something else.

EDIT: You can only do 2 things with a function pointer - cast it to a different function pointer; and call, but only with the original type.

See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/08/24/Function-pointers-in-C for details. Raymond Chen has another example here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx

EDIT2: However, you may make a number of no_ops (noop_IntInt_Int, noop_IntDouble_Double and so on... then if you match the types every time, that might work)

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the other functions in the table take multiple parameters.  I can add the same parameters to this function to make it homogenous.  Can I mix return types somehow?  I am declaring the table in this manner:
http://pastebin.com/8WhUZfiM

Comment: Your comment seems broken; can you paste the table declaration somewhere else? (github, pastebin, etc)

Comment: While you can *store* function pointers of different types in your table, you cannot *call* them with a different type. See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/08/24/Function-pointers-in-C for more details.

Comment: Yes the compiler has already warned me :)  But the original question still stands!

Comment: If you're careful enough, you can make a noop for every type combination. That should work. Looks horrible though. It's a good task for a code generator, not for human ;)

Comment: Yeah I could use C++, but then it wouldn't be as down to earth